# Adding Comments button against list of wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have call a list of phone records in wcf service. Now i need to add comments & feedback against all records, in such a way that user clicks the notes button and then enter the comments and feedback aaisnt a specific record.

Here is my class FOR notes

```
           public class CallNote
     {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ///<Summary>
    /// 
    ///</Summary>
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    ///<Summary>
    /// 
    ///</Summary>
    ///
    public string FeedBack { get; set; }
    ///<Summary>
    /// 
    ///</Summary>
    ///
    public string Login { get; set; }
    }
```

Class for callhistory

```
    public class CallHistory
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public int CallId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    ///
    public string Login { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Email { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Country { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string DialedNumber { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string CallStart { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string CallEnd { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string TariffDescription { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>

    }
```

and here is my controller

```
    public ActionResult CreateNote()
    {
        var result = Manager.GetUsersWhoHaveConsumedFreeCredit();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var callHistory = serializer.Deserialize<List<CallHistory>>(result);
        return View(callHistory.ToPagedList(1, Settings.PagingSize));

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNote(CallNote callnote)
    {
        CallNote_Db db = new CallNote_Db();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.callnote.Add(callnote);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("CallHistory");
            }
            return PartialView("CallHistory", callnote);          
    }

    public ActionResult UsersWhoHaveConsumedFreeCredit(int Id = 1)
    {
        var result = Manager.GetUsersWhoHaveConsumedFreeCredit(); ;
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var callHistory = serializer.Deserialize<List<CallHistory>>(result);
        CallNote callNote = new Models.CallNote();

        CallHistoryFilter callHistoryFilter = new Models.CallHistoryFilter();
        MyYelloAdminEntities db = new Models.MyYelloAdminEntities();
        {
            callHistoryFilter.Countries = db.Countries.ToList();
            callHistoryFilter.Countries.Insert(0, new Country { Title = "All", Prefix = "-1" });
            var model = new UsersWhoHaveConsumedFreeCredit
         {


             CallHistory = callHistory.ToPagedList(Id, Settings.PagingSize),
             CallHistoryFilter = callHistoryFilter

         };
            return View(model);

        }

    }
```

How i can add comments against each record.

Comment: Where do you want to add comments, in UI or in Wcf contract? Can you please provide little clarity in your problem?

Comment: In the UI but the comments should be againt specific login ids

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine two different WCF data contracts for your UI/display convenience,
then you can create a view model in your MVC project that is composed of these two datacontracts.
And once after you fetch WCF contracts to your MVC app then crate a datamapper(perhaps by using Automapper or a mapper of your choice) between WCF to your ViewModel and reverse the process while pushing data from UI back to WCF service.

Update based on your comments:

Please take a look at AutoMapper, it is a mapping tool to copy your property data from one type of entity to other type based on the mapping strategy you defined.

If you need to maintain comments/feedback at the currently logged in user then, you can track that on server and you need to only get the new comments from UI to controller and prepare the Model to save accordingly.

If you need to maintain comments/feedback at the respective user(the registered user who is providing the comments/feedback against your content) level, then you can maintain a hidden field on view and then you should post the userid and comments back to controller and save them.

Comment: Please guide me little more.
if i use autommaper. I will auto map my comments id with login id. and wehen ever ill add comment it will be saved against a specific login ID

Am i right?